# Vertx: Multiple consumers in multiple instances of a Verticle

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I my application I have two verticles (Standard one and NOT workers), one of which, say `VerticleA`, produces some messages and the other one, say `VerticleB`, consumes them. In `VerticleB` I create several consumers to consume these messages.

```
class VerticleA : AbstractVerticle() {
  val publisher: MessageProducer<String>
  
  fun start(promise: Promise<Void>) {

    publisher = vertx.eventBus().sender<String>("address")
               .setWriteQueueMaxSize(queueSize)

    vertx.setPeriodic(timeout) {
      if(publisher.writeQueueFull())
        return

      getAsyncMessages() { messages ->
         messages.forEach { publisher.wirte(it) }
      }
    }
  }
}

class VerticleB : AbstractVerticle() {
  
  val consumers: List<MyConsumers>
  
  override fun start(promise: Promise<Void>) {
    // Some initialization
    
    consumers = (1..count).map { createConsumer() }
  }

  fun createConsumer(): MessageConsumer<String> {
    val consumer = vertx.eventBus().consumer<String>("address")
    
    consumer.handler { message -> 
      consumer.pause()
      
      asyncProcess(message) { consumer.resume() }
    }
    return consumer
  }
}
```

When I deploy the application with only single instance of `VerticleB` i.e. with `DeploymentOptions.setInstances(1)` then everything works fine. But when I set the number instances to anything more than one then the consumers stop processing messages after processing few initial messages.

From logs I can see that each of the consumer consumes couple of messages and then stops consuming. The pause and resume logs are also in pairs i.e. for each `pause()` call there is a `resume()` call so the `asyncProcess()` does calls the callback even in case of error. Also the consumers have not ended.

I read the core manual here https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/ but I do not see anything that can point to solution of this.

Comment: i cant see the relevant code to where you are sending the message

Comment: In `Verticle1.start()` method there is method call `getAsyncMessages()`, in the lambda passed to it.